# Unir tablas con JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Solicito de su ayuda debido a que necesito realizar una unión de dos tablas en un query para poder crear una lista, pero no se como hacerlo, este es el query que cree:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.nombre_departamento,
       p.ciudad_departamento,
       f.nombre_facultad,
       p.estado_departamento
FROM par_departamento p, par_facultad f
WHERE p.id_facultad = f.id
```

Tabla ParDepartamento:

```
public class ParDepartamento implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "nombre_departamento")
private String nombreDepartamento;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "ciudad_departamento")
private String ciudadDepartamento;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "fecha_creacion")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fechaCreacion;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "estado_departamento")
private boolean estadoDepartamento;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_facultad", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private ParFacultad idFacultad;
```

Tabla ParFacultad:

```
public class ParFacultad implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "nombre_facultad")
private String nombreFacultad;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "ciudad_facultad")
private String ciudadFacultad;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "fecha_creacion")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fechaCreacion;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "estado_facultad")
private boolean estadoFacultad;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idFacultad")
private Collection<ParDepartamento> parDepartamentoCollection;
```

Intenté hacer esto y me genera error:

```
private EntityManager em;
em.createQuery("SELECT   p.id,p.nombre_departamento,p.ciudad_departamento,f.nombre_facultad,p.estado_departamento FROM par_departamento p, par_facultad f where p.id_facultad = f.id");
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ofrecer más código? ¿Intentas unir datos de la tabla par_departamento (p) y par_facultad (f)?

Comment: Por favor indícanos las entidades en Java y el diseño y relaciones en ellas

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza ya edite el post con las entidades

Comment: @dddenis me podrías indicar si necesitas algo mas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En JPQL, la unión `JOIN` se ejecuta directamente en las entidades, no necesitas escribirlo como si fuese SQL puro. JPQL se basa en las entidades cargadas por JPA y permite consultar sobre esas entidades más que por sobre las tablas. De la misma manera, la unión `JOIN` se realiza mediante las relaciones establecidas entre las entidades.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo seria el query JPQL:

```sql
SELECT
  dep.id,
  dep.nombreDepartamento,
  dep.ciudadDepartamento,
  fac.nombreFacultad,
  dep.estadoDepartamento
FROM ParDepartamento dep
    JOIN dep.idFacultad fac
```

Pero al parecer lo que realmente quieres obtener son los departamentos y sus facultades, así que quizás este JPQL resuelva tu problema:

```sql
SELECT dep FROM ParDepartamento dep -- por defecto traerá las facultades de cada ParDepartamento
```

Comment: mil gracias, si era lo que estaba buscando